# Suggestions for deploying AngularJS and NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular, sqlite

I'm building a basic web app using Angular, NodeJS, Express, and SQLite. The main concern here is pricing for a production environment. I want the cheapest way to deploy/maintain these. I chose SQLite so I don't have to worry about getting a production DB, though originally I wanted to use MongoDB. My question is, should I have my Angular and NodeJS app in the same project, and deploy my Angular app using express? Or should I have my Angular and NodeJS app separate? I originally had it together but was getting all kinds of errors. I did use a MEAN scaffolder which worked fine. But when I replaced MongoDB with TypeORM, I encountered the errors, so maybe my package.json/tsconfig.json was wrong? Regardless, what's the cheapest way to deploy my frontend and backend? I was thinking heroku/firebase, but want to hear some other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This could be quite a complex answer, but my short one would be to go serverless.

- Use AWS S3 to host your AngularJS single page application
- Cloudfront to expose your S3 bucket and host your site
- Write a Node.js library for your backend and deploy to Lambda
- Task AWS API Gateway to route requests to your library hosted on Lambda
- Use Firebase for your database.

You now have very little infrastructure to worry about, your app is highly scaleable, and costs are basically zero until you hit a very considerable amount of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a cheaper and easiest method to host try it with a digital ocean. Don't want to deploy front end in one server backend in another server

Docker is the easiest way to deploy it on the server

- Dockerize your project and deploy it with docker or docker-compose